# Is there BlockingMap as BlockingQueue in java?

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I'd like to have one BlockingMap data structure which is very similar to BlockingQueue. The take method of BlockingQueue will wait there until element is available. I'd like the get method of BlockingMap to wait there until the corresponding key is available?  Is this kind of data structure available that I can use ?

Comment: You can always combine ConcurrentHashMap with BlockingQueue, Future or Exchanger to achieve similar result.

Comment: @zjffdu interesting read on `BlockingMap` http://cs.oswego.edu/pipermail/concurrency-interest/2007-June/004211.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have simply used `BlockingQueue<Map.Entry<K,V>>` in the past. But recently, I came across this [Blocking Map for Java](http://sourceforge.net/projects/blockingmapforj/). Haven't used it myself, though.

Answer (score 12):

Here is an extremely simple implementation using BlockingQueue and ConcurrentHashMap:

```
public class BlockingMap<K, V> {
    private Map<K, ArrayBlockingQueue<V>> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    private BlockingQueue<V> getQueue(K key) {
        return map.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(1));
    }

    public void put(K key, V value) {
        // can also use add(value) if you want an exception thrown
        if ( !getQueue(key).offer(value) ) {
            System.err.println("Ignoring duplicate key");
        }
    }

    public V get(K key) throws InterruptedException {
        return getQueue(key).take();
    }

    public V get(K key, long timeout, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException {
        return getQueue(key).poll(timeout, unit);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `getQueue()` method could be simplified by using `putIfAbsent` and `getOrDefault`, respectively

Comment: I don't see how this class could work. If a thread does a get(), a queue is created and is waited on. Then, if another thread does put() over the same key, a new queue is created. But the previous queue never gets added to. So, the thread waiting on the first queue waits forever. Am I missing anything?

Comment: @elmart an invocation of `getQueue` with the second argument as `true` should indeed create a new queue for the same key, as far as I too understand. So `BlockingMap#put` will always create a new queue, which seems to be actually *not* desired, because it will cause the effect you are describing. Maybe if the second argument to `getQueue` is always `false` (or entirely dropped) then it should work.

Comment: Good point @elmart - I edited the code accordingly

Answer (score 4):

I hope [this](http://blockingmapforj.sourceforge.net/) is what you want.

```
public class BlockingHashMap<K,V>
extends java.lang.Object
implements BlockingMap<K,V>
```

**get**

```
public V get(java.lang.Object key)
```

Returns the value to which the specified key is mapped, or null if this map contains no mapping for the key.
Note that null is used as a special marker to indicate the absence of the requested key

Specified by:

```
get in interface java.util.Map<K,V>
```

Specified by:

```
get in interface BlockingMap<K,V>
```

**Parameters:**

```
key - the key whose associated value is to be returned
```

**Returns:**

```
the value to which the specified key is mapped, or null if this map contains no mapping for the key
```

**Throws:**

```
java.lang.ClassCastException - if the key is of an inappropriate type for this map
java.lang.NullPointerException - if the specified key is null and this map does not permit null keys (optional)
java.lang.IllegalStateException - if the map has been shut-down
```

Comment: `extends java.lang.Object` ? in java all object instances already extends it

Comment: That's how javadoc does it.