# How to do two-way message passing between two threads

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I have a third-party `MyService` class which is not thread safe, I have the same issue as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19484240/java-associate-object-with-each-thread-in-executor) with one difference: I need to submit `Callable`s not `Runnable`s.

With a regular `ThreadPoolExecutor` I would have done this:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);
// later in another thread
Future<String> result = executor.submit(() -> {
     // compute return value then return it
     return computed value
})
```

I would have then waited on the result future to get the result of callable.

But ExecutorService doesn't have a way to associate an object with each thread and the answer to the question above doesn't consider that the worker thread needs to communicate back to the Thread who submitted the task.

Using `ThreadLocal` has the obvious drawback at shutdown phase, I thought of a Map of Thread Ids to the results they need but `ConcurrentHashMap` doesn't provide a method that blocks current thread waiting for a key to be added and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20945984/is-there-blockingmap-as-blockingqueue-in-java) question doesn't give me a good answer: BlockingQueue<Map.Entry> is not what I need here and the `BlockingMap` library linked is very old.

So How do I achieve what I want ?

Comment: Have you tried passing some kind of thread-safe object to the Callable’s constructor? That way, you could get the computation result.

Comment: @rowing-ghoul I can't pass a thread-safe object, also I need the threads in the thread pool to own `MyService` objects not to create it in connection thread and pass it to.

Comment: @rowing-ghoul and I need to create multiple objects for each thread at startup not to create those objects in every request from connection threads

Answer (score 0):

I found a way, this solution is taken from `Executors` jdk implementation code. in short we use a `Future<Result>` to communicate back to the request thread like this:

```
class Task<T> extends CompletableFuture<T>
// in worker thread
MyService service = new MyServiceImpl();
while(!!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
     Task<T> task = blockingQueue.take();
     T result = ... // compute result
     task.complete(result)
}
// in request thread
Task<T> newTask = new Task<>();
blockingQueue.put(newTask)
return newTask.get() <--- ofcourse you can do others things with the future
```